# Java Custom ArrayList All Entries the Same

Tags: java, arraylist, h2

I have a custom an arraylist setup to hold data for me.
However when I call the arraylist items all the items are the same.

My arraylist loader.

```
public static ArrayList<Animal> getTblHerd() throws Exception {
    CC_H2 db = new CC_H2();
    db.Connect(Variables.getStrConn(), Variables.getStrUser(),
            Variables.getStrPassword(), "Embedded");
    ResultSet rs = db.query("Select HERD_ID FROM tblHerd ORDER BY HERD_ID ASC");
    ArrayList<Animal> alAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        int i = rs.getInt("HERD_ID");
        alAnimals.add(new Animal(i));
    }
    db.Disconnect();
    return alAnimals;
}
```

Animal Constructor

```
public Animal(int intAnimal_ID) throws Exception{
    CC_H2 db = new CC_H2();
    db.Connect(Variables.getStrConn(), "admin", "", "Embedded");
    ResultSet rs = db.query("Select * FROM tblHerd WHERE HERD_ID = "
            + intAnimal_ID);
    while (rs.next()) {
        setIntHerd_id(rs.getInt("Herd_ID"));
        setStrHerd_Tag_Letter(rs.getString("Herd_Tag_Letter"));
        setIntHerd_Tag_Num(rs.getInt("Herd_Tag_Num"));
        setStrHerd_Tag_Color(rs.getString("Herd_Tag_Color"));
        setStrHerd_Sex(rs.getString("Herd_Sex"));
        setStrHerd_Type(rs.getString("Herd_Type"));
        setDtHerd_Birthdate(rs.getDate("Herd_Birthdate"));
        setIntHerd_Sire(rs.getInt("Herd_Sire"));
        setIntHerd_Dam(rs.getInt("Herd_Dam"));
        setIntHerd_Owner(rs.getInt("Herd_Owner"));
        setDtHerd_TimeStamp(rs.getDate("Herd_TimeStamp"));
        setStrHerd_Status(rs.getString("Herd_Status"));
        setDtHerd_Status_Date(rs.getDate("Herd_Status_Date"));
    }
    db.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean they're the same? Same Herd_id? Same Tag_Letter? Are you sure you're getting different ids in getTblHerd? Maybe you could print or log `i` immediately after `int i = rs.getInt("HERD_ID");`

Comment: What have you tried? Are the entries in the database actually different? Is `rs.getInt("HERD_ID");` returning different ids?

Comment: check your id HERD_ID .i think it remains same every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code you listed should work as expected, the error is probably somewhere else.

- Check the data in your database
- Check the setters in the while loop do the right thing
- Check that the fields in the Animal class are not static
- If the problem persists, try to put something like `System.out.println(rs.getInt("Herd_ID") + ": " + rs.getString("Herd_Tag_Letter"));` into the where loop and check the output

Hope some of this helps :-)

Comment: I had the variables in the animal class set as static.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have created array list static

just remove **static** from there

Comment: Should not matter in this case: Not the **array list** is static but the **method creating** the array list is. A new `ArrayList` is created for each call to `getTblHerd()`.